# Pytorch: binary input and probabilistic output

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I am attempting a deep Reinforcement algorithm that takes a connect-4 position and outputs the probability of winning for Red (first player) using PyTorch in Python.

Problem is my input, output, and loss function of the NN. For each one, I don't know which to choose.

The positions are preferably encoded as a binary array of length 84 (7*6 board size * 2 layers for Red or Black Pieces). It is in binary and not as an integer because I use memory replay with large memory base and using binary datatype, I can store about 32 times the data than with int. Do you guys know rather I can use binary input or not?

Second, the output is preferably a number between 0 and 1 with 1 being a certain win for Red. But using RL update functions, the output target is of course never actually 0 or 1, It's somewhere in the middle (draws are 0.5 anyway). Which leaves the question: Which loss function should I use? MSE doesn't work with sigmoid as far as I know, and the Log loss functions need a one hot. Maybe I have to handle the output completely differently. I simply don't know, and thought perhaps some of you guys could give me some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have definitive answer to your questions, but have few things to point out:

1. Bitset (binary) as input. I think you can store replay buffer in compressed format, but convert it to one-hot enconding when passing it to network as input. Essentially, this is just compression method to store one-hot more efficiently in memory.
2. Network output as probability of red player win. I think it's important to clarify that in reality this probability will depend on player strategies. There is simple (not NN) value iteration method to estimate such probability: you just perform simulations from current position and count number of wins/losses. Strategy in simulations can be random, or some pretrained agent. Disadvantage of this simple method is that it's usually dog slow.
3. What method to choose. I don't have good intuition about it, but AFAIK usually you won't have one definitive answer to this question. Instead, you should try several different methods and see which performs better. If you're not familiar with RL domain yet, I would start from some course or book (for example: [https://www.amazon.com/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-Q-networks/dp/1788834240](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788834240) ) to gain understanding about the field and then implemented several algorithms from it and compared them.